# On Mac OSX Yosemite why does my computer download 500MB every day whether I am using it or not?

Tags: macos

I have Mac OSX Yosemite, 10.10.1 and halfway through last month my computer decided to download about 500MB every day. I even quit all programs and it still downloaded 447MB.
I am seeing this number in the network section of Activity Monitor and the Process name listed is nsurlsessiond. What is this downloading and how do I stop it?

Comment: google just the term `nsurlsessiond` and it seems to deal with the photo's app.  There is so much info tho I quit reading, you're not the only one by far that's complaining.....

Comment: If you run "lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP" in terminal it will show you who.

Comment: @Tyson It can't be the Photos app, because this is 10.10.1 and Photos was introduced in 10.10.3.

Comment: lsof doesn't return anything useful now so the nsurlsession must not be running. I'll check again later.

Comment: `nsurlsessiond` downloads data on behalf of other apps in the background. This includes iCloud Drive, Photos (10.10.3 & later), Photo Stream, and presumably third-party apps that implement it. You could monitor what domains it's communicating with by using something like [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at) so you can narrow down what program it is.

Comment: That network activity includes time machine backups

Comment: @fuzunspm nsurlsessiond has nothing to do with time machine backups.

Comment: @EDP I'm not talking about nsurlsessiond. If he look into total downloaded/uploaded activity, I meant that includes time machine backups

Comment: True.  If your comment would have been on top there wouldn't have been confusion :-)

Comment: Anyway, *nsurlsessionhd* has been a complete pita since 10.10.  It costed a lot more stress (and for many, money) than iOS'es 'Wifi Assist' and yet, there is no good solution other than blocking it, with the obvious result icloud and photos services don't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

nsurlsessiond deals with iCloud & also Spotlight.

- for Spotlight - Prefs > Spotlight > Search Results & switch off Spotlight Suggestions & Bing Web Searches.
- iCloud, some suggestions…

  - Disable iCloud Photo Library, Photo Stream & iCloud Photo Sharing from
    System prefs > iCloud - Photos [or equivalent, I can't remember the precise layout before Photos app]
  - If you have an iPhone, the same settings are in Settings > iCloud > Photos

Answer (score 2):

**nsurlsessionhd** can be disabled with

`sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plist`

**BUT** you run the risk of some Apple (and maybe non-Apple) apps not being able to connect to the internet, specifically App Store, iTunes, software updater, etc. If that is the case re-enable by replacing `unload` with `load` in the command above.